# Проблема с записью в массив Jquery

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/nilsons20000/8nsdovpy/64/ 
Перетащив одну карточку с статичным текстом , а вторую с текстарее, то сохранение в массив должно быть вот такое

```
{"cards1":["title","Static_text_from_block"],"cards2":["title","text_from_text_area"]"}
```

суть в том , что текст из текстарее должен сохранится там , куда его и перетащили , у меня это получилось со статичным текстом , но не выходит с текстарее. он сохраняется везде

```
{"cards1":["title","Static_text_from_block","text_from_text_area"],"cards2":["title","text_from_text_area"]"}
```

получается типа такого что то . 
Помогите , пожалуйста исправить

````
    $('#temp').on('click', function() {
            var result = {};
            $('.hexagon-cards-drop').each(function() {
                var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
                var elements = [];                
                        $(this).find('.wrap').each(function() {

                            var textarea = $(this).find("#my_textarea");
                                var text_write = '';
                                if(textarea.length){
                                     text_write = textarea.val();
                                     elements.push(text_write);
                                }else{
                                text_val = $(this).text();
                                elements.push(text_val);
                                }

                        });
                result[type] = elements
            });
            var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(myJsonString);
        });
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в этой строке. Вы в цикле обращаетесь к элементу по id. Элемент естественно находится каждый раз ведь вы ищете по всему документу.

```
    document.getElementById("my_textarea").value,
```

Вам нужно искать внутри вашего враппера. Напимер:

```
    var textarea = $(this).find("#my_textarea");
```

Потом проверять есть ли такой элемент и брать его значение

```
    var text_write = '';
    if(textarea.length){
            text_write = textarea.val();
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите,пожалуйста , я обновил вопрос ... вот так?

Comment: Да дад адададд дад да да да , получилось . вы лучший . просто лучший

Comment: Да, но у Вас там была проверка на наличие текста в textarea а сейчас вы ее убрали.

Comment: Да , знаю . Я верну всё обратно . главное, что работает . я почти умер (реально() думал , что сегодня меня турнут с работы и кранты . спасибо. очень выручили